# substitute text javascript .append()

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
 var app_name = "example_text"
         jq('.table_name > tbody:last').append(
            '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>app_name</td><td><button class="removeb">Remove</button></tr>'
         );
```

How do I use the var in .append() to as a substitute? Thanks!! Can I use %s, or is there another way of doing it in javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable into the string.

```
'<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>' + app_name + '</td><td><button class="removeb">Remove</button></tr>'
```

Or you can create your elements like this.

```
var app_name = "example_text"

var tr = $('<tr>');
$('<td>', {text: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'})
    .appendTo(tr);
$('<td>', {text: app_name})
    .appendTo(tr);
$('<td>').append($('<button>', className:'removeb', text:'Remove'}))
    .appendTo(tr);
jq('.table_name > tbody:last').append(tr);
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatination with the plus sign is an easy way to do this.

```
var app_name = "example_text";
jq('.table_name > tbody:last').append(
    '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>' + app_name + '</td><td><button class="removeb">Remove</button></tr>'
);
```